# How can I count how much wood a woodchuck chucks using Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, regex, grep

**TL;DR** Is there anything like `grep` in Excel that can help me count whole-word-only instances (e.g. "wood" but not "woodchuck") (and maybe their variations)?

So there's this poem, by mother goose:

```
How much wood could a woodchuck chuck 
If a woodchuck could chuck wood? 
As much wood as a woodchuck could chuck, 
If a woodchuck could chuck wood.
```

And it's a start, but there's still no hard numbers.

So I found a [very helpful post on Exceljet.net](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-specific-words-in-a-range) that suggests using a combination of SUBSTITUTE, LEN, and SUMPRODUCT.

If you imagine the above text to be contained in cells A1:A4, my first formula looked like this:

> =SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A1:A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE((UPPER(A1:A4)),UPPER("wood"),"")))/LEN("wood"))

note: my formula has "upper" included because the poem she sent me looks more like this

```
hOw MucH WOod cOuld a WOodCHucK CHUCk 
IF a wOoDchUCk couLD cHuck wood? 
aS muCH wOOD as a WOOdCHuCk coUlD ChuCK, 
iF a woODChUck coulD CHuCK WoOD.
```

But anyway, the result of this is 8, which is wrong.

I counted manually, there are only 4 woods, and 4 woodchucks. I don't want to count woodchucks, just the wood they would chuck (if indeed, they could chuck wood).

So now my current formula looks like this:

> =SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A1:A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE((UPPER(A1:A4)),UPPER("wood"),"")))/LEN("wood"))-(SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A1:A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE((UPPER(A1:A4)),UPPER("woodchuck"),"")))/LEN("woodchuck")))

And this technically works! but the truth is,  I'm not really trying to count the number of occurrences of the word "wood" in a mother goose poem, I need to count the number of instances of many different words, including ones that might be transposed, misspelled, or have random spaces or characters in them. I basically need something like grep inside Excel. Does such a thing exist? Stepping back to the scope of my original question, is there an easier way to write a formula to count whole-word-only instances and put the result in a cell?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops#22542835) is probably what you're looking for

Comment: And I always thought there was a line between 2 and 3 that read "A woodchuck would chuck,".  Apparently I do not know my mothergoose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard and complicated with worksheet functions because of the difficulty of determining word boundaries when having to deal with spaces and also various punctuations.

The VBA Regular Expression engine has a simple token `\b` that will detect word boundaries which is defined as the spot where a `word` character and `non-word` character, or the start or end of the line, meet.  A word character is one that is in the set of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

The VBA function:

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
'   or convert to Late Binding

Function ReCount(str As String, Pattern As String, _
    Optional CaseSensitive As Boolean = True) As Long

Dim objRegExp As RegExp
Dim objMatch As Match
Dim colMatches   As MatchCollection

    ' Create a regular expression object.
   Set objRegExp = New RegExp

   'Set the pattern by using the Pattern property.
   objRegExp.Pattern = Pattern

   ' Set Case Insensitivity.
   objRegExp.ignoreCase = Not CaseSensitive

   'Set global applicability.
   objRegExp.Global = True

   'Test whether the String can be compared.
    If (objRegExp.Test(str) = True) Then

   'Get the matches.
        Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(str)   ' Execute search.
        ReCount = colMatches.Count
    Else
        ReCount = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Usage:

```
=ReCount(A6,"\bwood\b")
```

Comment: Hi @Ron, thank you so much for your answer! I have set the reference for VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 and have pasted the entire string inside a single cell (A1). However, the answer evaluates to find only one instance. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @SuziLmrdo It finds `4` here.  Are certain the formula on the worksheet is pointing to the correct location?  and has the correct regex included?

Comment: what does the "convert to Late Binding" comment mean? Everything else has been done - I have the reference set, and I'm checking it by deleting and checking whether I can dimension them as RegEx, Match, MatchExpression (yes, the library shows them all). I tried putting the macro in both a module and the workbook, I can see and call the function. And to really make sure I idiot-proof it, I'm putting the string in A6 and literally copying/pasting your formula. I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: The macro should be in a regular module.  And, if you have set the reference, ignore the late-binding comment.  Can you upload a copy (with sensitive information removed) of your workbook to some sharing site, and post a link?  I will download it and see what the issue is.

Comment: here is a link [link] https://app.box.com/s/qu5kjx7ax6sl2p1su2jnp71bvlsj1qhn

Comment: @SuziLmrdo If you look at the function carefully (use the Function Arguments dialog box), you will see there is an `Optional` third argument having to do with case-sensitivity.  The default is Case-Sensitive.  You did not set that.  And, in your example, all was lower case.  But in your worksheet, that is not so.  So you need to set Case-Sensitive to False.  eg.:  `=ReCount(A6,"\bwood\b",FALSE)`

Comment: thank you. Indeed, I didn't see that earlier.  I am relatively new to VBA, and when I was looking at the code I kept trying to change this area of it:
  > ' Set Case Insensitivity.
  > objRegExp.ignoreCase = Not CaseSensitive. I am very much looking forward to learning more about code and appreciate your patience in helping me.

Comment: @SuziLmrdo Take a look at [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Answer (score 2):

This works for this instance, you may need to add other SUBSTITUTES for other punctuation.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "& "wood" & " "," " & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,".",""),"?","") & " ")))
```

This now looks for the full word surrounded by spaces, which is why we need to remove the punctuation.  Since SEARCH is not case sensitive we do not need the UPPER.

[image]

---

The above will only count 1 per cell no matter the number of times the word is found.

This will count all:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(" " & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1:A4),".", " "),"?"," ") & " ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" " & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1:A4),"."," "),"?"," ") & " ",UPPER(" wood "),"")))/LEN(" wood "))
```

[image]

Comment: Seems this causes an issue if the word is located at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: @Appleoddity It doesn't but it does have a problem counting if the word appears twice.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner, I think I just ran into that problem you mentioned above. If you paste the entire string into a single cell, the answer evaluates as "1".

Comment: @SuziLmrdo see edit.

Comment: @ScottCraner, the first formula is unable to count more that 4 occurrences. Second formula is working but few times it failed to count all occurrences. Just  check it. ☺

Comment: ,,Cont  like try to add `wood` as last word with line 2 & 4, you found count remains 4.

Comment: @RajeshS fixed see edit.

Comment: @ScottCraner,, nice now is working ,,, perfect 10 ☺

Answer (score -1):

[image]

*This simple formula will count the **Wood** in data Range.*

```
=COUNTIF(E53:E56,"*wood*")
```

**EDITED:**

[image]

*The occurrence of **Wood** can be counted using the Helper Column also.*

- In Helper Column write **Wood** in all possible formats.
- Write this formula & fill down.
- Finally Sum the Count.

`=SUMPRODUCT(LEN($E$74:$E$77)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($E$74:$E$77,F74,"")))/LEN(F74)`

- Adjust the cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Your formula is not doing what you think it is doing, even though you get the expected result with this data set.  Try putting two or more instances of `wood` in any of the lines, and you will see that the total will not change.

Comment: @Rajesh, thank you very much for your answer. It is unfortunate my original question has each line inside a separate cell with four lines total, because I think the formula above is counting the number of cells with an occurrence of the word, rather than individual instances of the word, irrespective of how many cells they are spread across. When I tried pasting the entire string inside cell E2, for example, the value inside of F2 changed to 1.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thanks for raising a good point, the same  issue I've got with #Scott's formula. Second one is working sometimes but  also getting Failed in most of the Cases and his first formula is exactly behaving like mine. Let me find the correction. ☺

Comment: @RajeshS, your answer and edit kind of miss the point of the question.  The issue isn't finding "wood", it's not counting it when it's part of "woodchuck".

Comment: @fixer1234, I've picked this from OP,, "help me count whole-word-only instances (e.g. "wood" but not "woodchuck")", and I think others also worked on that only,,, since there formula also counting the   WOOD, plz suggest if any other idea should have apply on this. ☺